# Visual Studio docker skipping project because not found, then restores and eventually builds but is slow

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

I am trying to get to the bottom of a slow (30 seconds for vanilla default worker service) docker build process which I referenced one project class library from, I have the following docker file:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Libertas.Tickers.Stream/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj", "Libertas.Tickers.Stream/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Libertas.Tickers.Stream/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Libertas.Tickers.Stream"
RUN dotnet build "Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Libertas.Tickers.Stream.dll"]
```

When I right click and build the projects docker file I see the lines saying not found:

```
4>Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.504MB
4>
4>Step 1/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
4> ---> 7be7431e6153
4>Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
4> ---> Using cache
4> ---> dda29b40eefe
4>Step 3/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
4> ---> c4155a9104a8
4>Step 4/17 : WORKDIR /src
4> ---> Using cache
4> ---> 8424cf707044
4>Step 5/17 : COPY ["Libertas.Tickers.Stream/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj", "Libertas.Tickers.Stream/"]
4> ---> 791c6f181247
4>Step 6/17 : RUN dotnet restore "Libertas.Tickers.Stream/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj"
4> ---> Running in 870556eed511
4>  Determining projects to restore...
4>  Skipping project "/src/Libertas.Common/Libertas.Common.csproj" because it was not found.
4>  Skipping project "/src/Libertas.Common/Libertas.Common.csproj" because it was not found.
4>  Restored /src/Libertas.Tickers.Stream/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj (in 8.01 sec).
4>Removing intermediate container 870556eed511
4> ---> 06c7118a1cb7
4>Step 7/17 : COPY . .
4> ---> e8f81702a397
4>Step 8/17 : WORKDIR "/src/Libertas.Tickers.Stream"
4> ---> Running in fec96fed84a3
4>Removing intermediate container fec96fed84a3
```

And then eventually restores the packages and builds without error:

```
4> ---> 16aacaa1da46
4>Step 9/17 : RUN dotnet build "Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
4> ---> Running in ffd594ede300
4>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+7fb82e5b2 for .NET
4>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
4>
4>  Determining projects to restore...
4>  Restored /src/PolygonIo.WebSocket/PolygonIo.WebSocket.csproj (in 5.98 sec).
4>  Restored /src/Unified.EnterpriseIntegration/Unified.EnterpriseIntegration.csproj (in 9.91 sec).
4>  Restored /src/Libertas.Common/Libertas.Common.csproj (in 9.92 sec).
4>  Restored /src/Libertas.Tickers.Stream/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.csproj (in 9.92 sec).
4>/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4364,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "/root/.nuget/packages/system.reactive/4.4.1/buildTransitive/netcoreapp3.0/../../lib/netstandard2.0/System.Reactive.dll" to "/app/build/System.Reactive.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file '/app/build/System.Reactive.dll' because it is being used by another process.  [/src/Unified.EnterpriseIntegration/Unified.EnterpriseIntegration.csproj]
4>  PolygonIo.WebSocket -> /app/build/PolygonIo.WebSocket.dll
4>  Unified.EnterpriseIntegration -> /app/build/Unified.EnterpriseIntegration.dll
4>  Libertas.Common -> /app/build/Libertas.Common.dll
4>  Libertas.Tickers.Stream -> /app/build/Libertas.Tickers.Stream.dll
4>Build succeeded.
```

Is there any way to skip this not found step or speed up the process, with lots of docker images doing the same its taking an age to build the solution (containing many docker worker projects) as a whole.